# Server Bandwidth issues unexplained by Stats.. what else could it be?

Tags: apache-2.4, bandwidth

So hit my server bandwidth cap (shared hosting) at 4GB today and i'm absolutely baffled as to why.

All my site does is serve bytes of data to a few apps (about 3-4 devices for the past few weeks only). All traffic HTTP. there are no email accounts, and barely any FTP activities.

Each app/device polls a 3-4 php scripts on the server at 5second interval..
each php script outputs mere bytes of data..

I have checked the AW STATS.. and did my own math on the logs and all i got was roughly 500MB bandwidth against the reported 4GB

Exhibit A: 
[image]
I also checked out WEBALIZER and it shows around 600MB bandwidth consumption only w/c is close enough to my own AW STATS calculations.

Exhibit B:
[image]
So i'm scratching my head at the moment and don't know where else to look.

Am I being attached? Where is it coming from? What is it hitting? It's not in the logs?

Please help.

Comment: Perform a packet capture, then analyze that.

Comment: Are you implying that the *only* traffic you server generates is web traffic? What about everything else going on with the system?

Comment: @gregL  - hi there.  Yes. I should've mentioned this sorry. Everything is just HTTP at the moment and barely any FTP.. there are no email accounts, nothing. It's all HTTP serving bytes of data to keep apps updated